# How do I open a cloned project from github in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: git, github, netbeans, clone

I cloned the github project using git bash command. Now, how do i open that cloned project in my netbeans ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbAwj.png)

this is the image when i tried cloning with the help of netbeans

Comment: On cloning the project by netbeans, it doesn't prompt for uid and password after pasting the repository url, so i did with git bash and I;m stuck with how do i open the cloned project to netbeans. Please help.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about NetBeans, but the cloned project is simply a folder, what do you mean by "how do I open that cloned project"? Isn't it just like opening any other files or folders?